# How to fetch data Message wise?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sql-order-by

I have table like this.

```
thread_id, message_id, tomsg, frommsg, msg, time, readstatus
1,1,k@k.com,j@k.com,Hi,"2013-12-04 18:06:58",0
2,1,j@k.com,k@k.com,Hello,"2013-12-06 11:11:11",0
3,1,k@k.com,j@k.com,"How R U ?","2013-12-18 11:55:15",0
4,2,a@b.com,b@b.com,sem1,"2013-12-04 18:06:58",1
5,2,b@b.com,a@b.com,sem2,"2013-12-06 11:11:11",0
```

Here `, Comma` Separates the column data.
I don't have enough reputation so I can't Upload Image.

Now suppose I want dat that have only last thread of each message then what I ll have to do ?
i.e. from message_id 1 last whole thread 3 row should be returned.
any suggestion please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.thread_id, t.message_id, t.tomsg, t.frommsg, t.msg, t.time, t.readstatus 
FROM (SELECT t.thread_id, t.message_id, t.tomsg, t.frommsg, t.msg, t.time, t.readstatus 
      FROM thread t ORDER BY t.message_id, t.thread_id DESC
     ) AS t
GROUP BY t.message_id
```

Comment: Sir suppose i want to pur where clause in it that frommsg or tomsg have id = k@k.com, for that what I ll have to do ?